# Use 2 forms to trigger $(document).on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am using a script in jquery that will be triggered when in update one form called `class="data"`.

```
$(document).on('change', '.data'  function(){  #my-code-here }
```

What i want to do is trigger my script using 2 forms, something like this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.date', '.formxpto',  function(){ #my-code-here}
```

So when i change any of the 2 forms (date or formxpto), my script will trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you just want to bind multiple classes to the event, and you do that by using a comma between them in your jquery selector.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.date, .formxpto',  function(){ 
  console.log('changed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="date">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>

<select class="formxpto">
  <option>foo</option>
  <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, i forget to remove  ' ' between my form class